# Matrix store. Where are we going to do?

Tags: java

We're trying to read a file that contains a sudoko plate with integers and dots for the empty spaces. We have no problem reading the file using `scanner` and `new File`, but when we can't print the plate in a `9 x 9` matrix.

We wish to load the file and store it in an  `9 x 9` matrix with a while loop. But we get the following error when doing so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at Sodoku.main(Sodoku.java:19)
```

And were not sure, what we're doing wrong. 
So far we have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sodoku{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws java.io.FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("Sudoku.txt"));
        int m = 9;
        int n = 9;
        int[][] a = new int [m][n];
        while (input.next()!=null){
            for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    a[i][j]= input.nextInt();
            }   

        }
        //print the input matrix
        System.out.println("The input sorted matrix is : ");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Probably should be using `while( input.hasNextInt() )`

Comment: Yes we've tried that, but then we just get 9*9 zeros in a vertical line.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Can you post your input file?  Are you sure it consists only of integers and white space?

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of the contents the file have, is that enough? :)

Comment: Well "." isn't an int so that's not going to work.  I think you didn't read the instructions for your assignment.

Comment: `input.next()` consumes input.

Comment: Arrrhh i see, I thought that might be the case. But What do I do in that situation, can we use another command, instead of hasNextInt? :)

Comment: Given that the input format won't work with either `next()` or `nextInt()`, I'm sure your instructor told you what you needed to do (or at least gave a hint).  You should talk to them first, you're really far off and just guessing.  Don't guess, try to actually work it out.

Comment: What number would you like to have stored in the matrix when there's a dot in the file?

Comment: just a dot, to replace later on with inputs from the user :-) - I've added the preferred format that it should look like after the modifications.

Comment: No, an `int[][]` can only store `int` values, and `.` is not an `int`.  You could use a `char[][]` I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method i can think of would be to load the file as an string and then parse it to the desired format. Here you have the code. Not pretty, but will do the trick:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Sudoku {

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
    throws IOException 
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    static int[][] parse(String path) throws IOException {
        String input = readFile(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
        int [][] array = new int[10][10];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (chars[i] == '\n') {
                x = 0;
                y++;
                continue;
            } else if (chars[i] == '.') {
                array[y][x] = -1;
                x++;
                continue;
            }
            array[y][x] = Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]);
            x++;
        }

        return array;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException {
        int m = 9;
        int n = 9;
        int[][] a = parse("Sudoku.txt");
        //print the input matrix
        System.out.println("The input sorted matrix is : ");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if (j==3 || j==6) System.out.print ("| ");
                if (a[i][j]==-1) {
                    System.out.print(". ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("");
            if (i==2 || i==5) System.out.println("----------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

With the file Sudoku.txt

```
.1.3..8..
5.96..7..
7.4.95.2.
4.....1..
.28.71.63
...2.495.
6.3..9..7
...43.516
.52.8..4.
```

Outputs the following:

```
. 1 . | 3 . . | 8 . . 
5 . 9 | 6 . . | 7 . . 
7 . 4 | . 9 5 | . 2 . 
----------------------
4 . . | . . . | 1 . . 
. 2 8 | . 7 1 | . 6 3 
. . . | 2 . 4 | 9 5 . 
----------------------
6 . 3 | . . 9 | . . 7 
. . . | 4 3 . | 5 1 6 
. 5 2 | . 8 . | . 4 .
```

Answer (score 0):

By using input.next in the while you move the pointer(you consume one of the values), you can use

```
while (input.hasNext()==true){
```

This will not move the pointer it will only verify it has a "next" value

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but I think using `input.next()` as a while statements results in loosing this value later on ( when you are using `input.nextInt()` it' s next value from a file, not the one from the statement). Try using integer as a temporary container for that value:

```
int tmp;
while(tmp=input.next()!=null) and later on a[i][j]= tmp;
```

or you can try using different statement like while(`input.hasNext()`)